# How to export an object with methods and properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, electron, require

I have two js files in Electron (which uses Nodejs) and I try to export from one and require in another.

app.js:

```
App = {
 server: {
   host: '192.168.0.5',
   user: 'root',
 }
 ping: function() {
 }
}

exports.App = App
```

I have tried every way possible of exporting, including `module.exports = App`, `module.exports.App = App` and so on.

ping.js first attempt:

```
var App = require('../app.js') // I have also tried adding .App to the end
console.log(App) // This returns an object which contains the App object
```

ping.js second attempt:

```
var App = require('../app.js')
App.x = 'y'
console.log(App) // this returns an object which contains the App object and the x property
```

It may appear that `App` contains another `App` object, but `console.log(App.App)` says it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd to do solve this would be to make sure I'm using the full path to the required module, as in:

```
const Path = require('path')
const App = require(Path.join(__dirname,'../app')) // the .js isn't needed here.
```

Note that this assumes that the `app.js` file is in the immediate parent directory of the one in which the application runs.

If that doesn't work, I'd make sure the files are where you think they are, and that the process you're running is located within the file system where you think it is. You can determine this by adding this to the top of your main script file:

```
console.log("current working directory:",process.cwd())
```

Or in es6:

```
console.log(`current working directory: %s`, process.cwd())
```

If the printed directory doesn't match your assumptions, modify your `require` statement accordingly.

And for the record, the "correct" way to export your App map would be to:

```
const App = {
  ... 
}
module.exports = App
```

Or using es7:

```
export default App = {
  ...
}
```

(See [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) for more on es7 modules.)

Either way, you'd then require the module as:

```
const App = require(PATH_TO_APP)
```

Comment: I have found the problem. I was using `require('app.js')` from index.html, but `ping.js` was only required from `app.js`. I have added `require('ping.js')` in index.html and it worked.